# how to check if a word is in alphabetical order in python

Tags: python

So i'm trying to do this python program that will print if a word is in alphabetical order or not. I'm new to python. I don't really know much. I tried to gather up this program but it has some errors.

////Code////

```
 b = "hello world"
 words = b.split()
 i = b.split()
 # sort the list
 words.sort()
 for word in i:
 i.append(word)
 if i == words:
 print(True)
 else:
 print(False)
```

///Error///

this is the error message 
Line 2: Syntax Error: bad input (' ')

Comment: for one, you are missing the indents. That’s bad

Comment: also you don't need to `split()` twice, just copy the list using the `[:]` operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking if a string is in alphabetical order in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661479/checking-if-a-string-is-in-alphabetical-order-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checking if a string is in alphabetical order in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661479/checking-if-a-string-is-in-alphabetical-order-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note:
1. You want to sort the word in the same case. If you do `ord("H")` and `ord("e")` you'll see that Python considers "H" to be before "e".
2. You can directly compare the sorted output, you don't need to do it character by character.
3. You don't need that final `if` statement.

```
words = "Hello world ace"
words = [word.lower() for word in words.split()]
for word in words:
    print(sorted(word) == list(word))
```

Comment: how can accomplish this in your answer "The word must be terminated by a blank, so that the automaton will know when
it has read all the characters" ?!