# Eliminate duplicates in dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file separated by tabs:

[image]

I need only to focus in the two first columns and find, for example, if the pair A-B appears in the document again as B-A and print A-B if the B-A appears. The same for the rest of pairs.

For the example proposed the output is:
· A-B
& C-D

```
    dic ={}
    import sys
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import csv

    colnames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']

    data = pd.read_csv('koko.csv', names=colnames, delimiter='\t')

    col1 = data.col1.tolist()
    col2 = data.col2.tolist()

    dataset = list(zip(col1,col2))
    for a,b in dataset:
        if (a,b) and (b,a) in dataset:
        dic [a] = b
print (dic)

output = {'A': 'B', 'B': 'A', 'D': 'C', 'C':'D'}
```

How can I avoid duplicated (or swapped) results in the dictionary?

Comment: If one of the below solutions helped, please consider accepting it (green tick on the left), so other users know. Or, of course, feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D']
col_2 = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([col_1,col_2]), columns = ['Col1', 'Col2'])

df['combined'] = list(zip(df['Col1'], df['Col2']))

final_set = set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in df['combined'])
```

final_set looks like this:

```
 {('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')}
```

The output contains more than A-B and C-D because of the second row that has B-C

Comment: But B-C is not a possible answer because there is no C-B

Comment: What is the expected behavior for the second row then? it has B for Col1 and C for Col2. I must be misinterpreting the problem

Answer (score 0):

The below should work,

example df used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['A','C','D','B','D','A'], 'Col2' : ['B','D','C','A','C','B']})
```

> This is the function I used:

```
 temp = df[['Col1','Col2']].apply(lambda row: sorted(row), axis = 1)
 print(temp[['Col1','Col2']].drop_duplicates())
```

useful links:

[checking if a string is in alphabetical order in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661479/checking-if-a-string-is-in-alphabetical-order-in-python)

[Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas)

Comment: Ah, sorry wasn't clear that the output should be limited to A-B and C-D, as the example given only contains A-B and C-D entries... and states "The same for the rest of pairs."

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['A','C','D','B','D','A','E'],
                   'Col2' : ['B','D','C','A','C','B','F']})

df = df.drop_duplicates()\
       .apply(sorted, axis=1)\
       .loc[df.duplicated(subset=['Col1', 'Col2'], keep=False)]\
       .drop_duplicates()

#   Col1 Col2
# 0    A    B
# 1    C    D
```

**Explanation**

The steps are:

1. Remove duplicate rows.
2. Sort dataframe by row.
3. Remove unique rows by keeping only duplicates.
4. Remove duplicate rows again.